# Can I make tab-completion filter files by extension?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

Assume `myprogram` only consumes `*.data` files as command line arguments. In terminal, when we do

```
$ myprogram <tab>
```

we want only the `*.data` files to be listed for tab auto-complete. How is this behavior achieved? The shell being used is Bash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Option 1

Type the following into your bash shell

`complete -f -X '!*.data' myprogram`

the `-f` option tells `complete` to only complete based on file names, not directories. the `-X` option allows you to specify the filter pattern.

### Option 2

Note: This solution is global. It will affect tab-completion in every directory and on every command (meaning things like `cd` or `rm`, as well as `myprogram`). It works by allowing you to specify file extensions that **will not** appear in tab-complete. This is not exactly what you asked for, but if there aren't many files other than `*.data` in your working directory, excluding all the options won't be too much of a pain. For both these reasons this option is probably not what you want but it is still worth noting.

In the file `~/.bash_profile` add the line

```
FIGNORE=".py:.txt:.out:.exe:.c:<etc>"
```

The syntax there is to create a colon-separated list of the file extensions you want to ignore. After saving the new `.bash_profile` you must type `. ~/.bash_profile` for the changes you made to take effect.

### Further info

For more info about the complete command check out [Programmable Completion Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) in the Bash manual.

Comment: For more info about the `complete` command check out http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html

Comment: Is that `<etc>` intended to be "whatever else you want", or does it have special meaning for `FIGNORE` and is intended literally?

Comment: What ever else you want

Answer (score 3):

Better use `_filedir` instead of "raw" `complete`.

**Justification**

- `grep _filedir -r $(pkg-config --variable=completionsdir bash-completion) | wc -l`
- tilde (`~`) paths are being expanded
- Prefixes are removed for directories, i.e. for `/home/tux/Do<TAB><TAB>`, the list you get as a reply removes '/home/tux' and is thus much more compact
- Easier to implement and more failsafe

**MWE**

Write a file "completions/myprogram", which you source by `. completions/myprogram`. Content:

```
_myprogram()
{
    # init bash-completion's stuff
    _init_completion || return

    # fill COMPREPLY using bash-completion's routine
    _filedir '@(data)'
}
complete -F _myprogram myprogram
```